# How can I add customer methods to ENUM to get string value of the value I am using (if needed)

Tags: java, string, enums, enumeration

I am creating an ENUM for some personal side project, and I wanted it to return the String value of each value if I desire to store the value as String variable in my code somewhere else.

for example:

public enum Month {

```
JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL,
MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST,
SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER,

ID {
    public String id(Month month) {
        return month.toString();
    }
},

VALUE {
    public String value(Month month) {
        return month.toString();
    }
},
```

}

I would like to add id(); value() methods in my ENUM (let's say this is the one)

and when I chained either ID, or VALUE, I would like to get the String values; currently, it returns Month type.

I was trying if this works, but the return type of both ID and VALUE were still Month type.

Thanks in advance!!

(If possible reply in a way, so that I can promote your answer as part of thank you)

Comment: Fix your formatting.

Comment: Perhaps you should examine the actual `java.time.Month` enum and its `getDisplayName` method.